# Is PHP Routing with similar_text bad for search engines?

Tags: search-engine

My website should only have one index.php that checks the requested URL and displays the right content via include(...) respectively.

Right now I am using `similar_text` for URLs that doesn't exist on website. Than the most simliar path should be choosen.

But I heard that simliar URLs that gives the same content aren't good for search engines.

So does it have a bad effect to search engines like Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All urls with the same content are counted as double.
You should return `404 not found` header for all urls wich do not mach exactly with yours.

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
echo "<h1>Error 404 Not Found</h1>";
```

More detailes about google's attitude see in [documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en)